# Change entry point to npm dependency

Tags: npm, package.json

I'm dependending on a library that publishes different module packages to npm (commonjs, ES2015, UMD bundles..) and specifies `commonjs/index.js` as the `main` point of the application.

However, I need my app to use the UMD bundle instead so I would need it to be `bundles/index.umd.js` instead.

I figured I could do this by looking into installed 'node_modules' and changing it directly in the `package.json` of downloaded library, but thats a very hacky thing to do.

Is there some other way of chanding the `main` file for the dependency?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this wiht npm or yarn?